# Validation rule IF picklist value is already selected then you cannot change a percentage field to 100%

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

Im trying to create a validation rule that states that if you have a picklist value then you cannot change a percantage field to 100%. Why  is what I have letting it save?

```
AND( 
ISPICKVAL( FedCapture__Our_Role__c,'Subcontractor'), 
ISPICKVAL( FedCapture__Our_Role__c,'JV - Minority Partner'), 
ISPICKVAL( FedCapture__Our_Role__c,'JV - Managing Partner'), 
AND( FedCapture__Workshare__c = 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have one field contain multiple values. Right now your rule says the record is invalid if three different values are simultaneously selected. But that will never happen. You instead want:

```
AND(
    Percentage_Field__c = 1,
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist_Field__c, "Value 1"),
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist_Field__c, "Value 2"),
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist_Field__c, "Value 3")
    )
)
```

Please note that logical clauses in formulae join all the clauses *inside* the function call. So having `AND(singleClause)` isn't any different than `singleClause` on its own.

Comment: I think you also want to change it so you compare to 100, not 1, but need to double check.